# Why ctx.send(arg) doesn't send arg in Discord?

Tags: python, discord.py

I just started making my own Discord bot, but even this simple test code won't work

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?',intents=intents)

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)
```

Both

```
message.content.startswith('$hello'):
```

and

```
await message.channel.send('Hello!')
```

work as expected, I have tried to change the command_prefix to other symbols, with no luck

Comment: Define "won't work"? What are doing and what are you expecting? Are you invoking the `/test` command with an argument for it to send? Is there an error message? "Won't work" isn't very helpful so any extra info on what you're doing and expecting makes it easier for others to help and more likely you'll get an answer.

Comment: No matter how I change the command, its prefix or the arguments, nothing happens. No error, no console output, nothing.

Comment: did you turn on the message intent button on developer portal?

Answer (score 2):

I think your issue might be related to having both a `discord.Client` and a `discord.Bot` class instantiated together. You only need one or the other - not both. It's not shown but I'm taking a hunch that you're doing `client.run(TOKEN)` and therefore, the command isn't getting registered.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?',intents=intents)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {bot.user}')


@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

This ran perfectly for me.

[image]